# meta logo background colour doesn't match

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, design

It appears that the background of the meta logo doesn't match the background colour used for the rest of the page -- would it be possible to bring these in line?

**EDIT:**

According to the eyedropper in Photoshop, the meta logo background is #FEFEFE, whilst the page background is #FFFFFF.

This is as about as subtle a difference as there could be, and it possibly is only noticeable to:

- People using TFTs, where viewing at "odd" angles, gives an artificial boost to contrast
- People using screens calibrated with colourimeters
- People that have good eyesight (possibly might need "better than average").

Comment: Lay down a screenshot?

Comment: Take a photo of it, post it on Flickr and then tweet it back for all to compare

Comment: The SO logo is OK, as is the SU one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks fine on my computer, but I can kind-of see the outline of the logo.

Comment: So if you can see the outline, there must be a difference, which is what I'm trying to point out :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine in Chrome 3.0.195.4

Edit:
Actually, I'm sure that's a function of my LCDs. As Rowland points out, the image shows a background of #FEFEFE (off white) and the page background is set to #FFFFFF (pure white).

Comment: Just checked with a screenshot in Photoshop, and it also gives a difference between #FEFEFE and #FFFFFF